# Emit event (or alternative) from grandchild component Angular 9

Tags: angular, events, angular-services, emit

I have structure like AngularJS application -> Angular component (main) -> child component -> grand-child component. There is click event happening on my grandchild component and I want to emit event to AngularJS application. I have added listner in my AngularJS application and if I emit event from main component, then it works, but not from grandchild. Chaining events every level up might be a solution but doesn't look optimized as there can  be many such events. I read on some thread that it is not good practice to emit event from service (Still I tried in my case but anyways didn't work). Is there any other way?

Comment: I have the same Application structure. I use Angular downgradeable service or AngularJs upgradeable service to communicate between all my grand-childs and AngularJs entites. We are of course in the path to converting them all to Angular and deprecating AngularJs eventually. If I understand correctly, maybe ask a more technical question on why this doesn't work for you if you want to continue with this path?

Comment: We too are on the way to upgrade but doing step by step so need integration of both meanwhile. My architect want to keep component independent of service endpoints so client should call services and feed the data to component whenever required. Chaining events should work but that would be last option I'll go for. I am saying that emit() from service doesn't work for me. It doesn't call client's listner. Could you please ellaborate on the upgradable/downgradable services you are talking about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

take a look at RxJS Subject.
in the grandChild whenever click event happens, do the `subject.next();` then in the AngularJS application subscribe to it.

Comment: Okay. Let me give it a try. I'll get back with outcome. Thanks.

Comment: Could you please ellaborate on how AngularJS will subscribe? I mean how will it get service reference to do subscribe?

Comment: at first in a service, define a property as Subject then in another property get its `.asObservable()` , then on a method you do the `.next()` of your main Subject property, after that in your destination component, get that property you made it as `asObservable` in the service and subscribe to it. if you need an example, let me know.

Comment: and you can get your services using dependency injection in every component

Comment: Thanks for revert. Seems my question in comment was not clear. My AngularJS application is independent and I am injecting this Angular component in it. My question was how my AngularJS application will subscribe to observable in component service? Nonetheless, I have implemented your RxJS recommandation and it is working.Only thing is I need to use parent component as bridge between AngularJS and grandchild but i could skip all other middle levels. If I can subscribe to observable of component service in AngularJS, I would be able to elliminate parent component dependancy too.

Comment: I think you need to convert your service, take a look at this [link](https://www.codelord.net/2016/01/07/adding-the-first-angular-2-service-to-your-angular-1-app/) maybe helps you.

Comment: It looks like too much considering this is just a stop gap arrangement. I could initialize returned response to parent control attribute and used service to transfer it to my child component so I am good for now. Noetheless, your comments shown me path and it indeed provided solution so I am marking it as answer. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Please try below given code

```js
// --------------------------------------
// app.component.html

<div>
  <span>Master to Child </span><input type="textbox" [(ngModel)]='master'>
</div>

<app-child [childToMaster]=master (childToParent)="childToParent($event)"></app-child>

<app-grand-child [childToMaster]=master (childToParent)="childToParent($event)"></app-grand-child>

// --------------------------------------
// app.component.ts

import { Component, Output,EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  //passing values from parent to child
  master : String="send from parent";
  
  //Getting value from child
  childToParent(name){
    this.master=name;
  }

}

// --------------------------------------
// app.module.ts

import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppChildComponent } from './app-child.component';
import { AppGrandChildComponent } from './app-grand-child.component';


@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, AppChildComponent, AppGrandChildComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }

// --------------------------------------
// app-grand-child.component.ts

import { Component, Input, Output,EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-grand-child',
  template: `
    <input type="textbox" [(ngModel)]='masterName'> 
    <button (click)="sendToParent(masterName)" >sendToParent</button>
    <div>{{masterName}}</div>
  `
})
export class AppGrandChildComponent {
  //getting value from parent to child
  @Input('childToMaster') masterName: string;

  @Output() childToParent = new EventEmitter<String>();

  

  sendToParent(name){
    //alert("hello");
    this.childToParent.emit(name);
  }
}



// --------------------------------------
// app-child.component.ts

import { Component, Input, Output,EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  template: `
    <input type="textbox" [(ngModel)]='masterName'> 
    <button (click)="sendToParent(masterName)" >sendToParent</button>
    <div>{{masterName}}</div>
  `
})
export class AppChildComponent {
  //getting value from parent to child
  @Input('childToMaster') masterName: string;

  @Output() childToParent = new EventEmitter<String>();

  

  sendToParent(name){
    //alert("hello");
    this.childToParent.emit(name);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Pooja. This is chaining I have mentioned in my question and it would work too but I am in search of better option if available as there would be many such events in my case. If not, I'll fall to this solution and mark it as answer.

Comment: Okay, another way is "Sharing Data with a Service"

Comment: https://fireship.io/lessons/sharing-data-between-angular-components-four-methods/